# Oracle Merge to be Scheduled Job

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, merge

I have written two merge statements that I intend to be set up on an Oracle 10g (10.2) database, I will send these to the Oracle DBA to be evaluated before being implemented, but I'm quite a noob when it comes to Oracle PL/SQL coding so wanted to ask the question here whether there is something obviously wrong with these statements before looking a fool in front of the DBA.

In this scenario, I have an engineering database that is setup; the tag number (component.cmpnt_name) is often used as a basis to create other equipment tags or document numbers in the database. Only, in later workflows the Tag Number may get changed, but, that change does not filter down and change the equipment or document numbers automatically so we are left with mismatches.

So this is a bit of a sledgehammer approach to making the equipment names (cs_tag_name) and document name (dwg_name) match again. The Tag Number naming convention often has spaces (whitespace) within it which is done on purpose and required, but these spaces are trimmed when the equipment and document numbers are first created.

So the idea is to trim the spaces out of the cmpnt_name field, then update the cs_tag_name and the dwg_name fields accordingly. I hope that made sense. Merge code below.

Merge 1, updating the dwg_name = trimmed cmpnt_name ...

```
MERGE INTO drawing
USING 
(
SELECT c.cmpnt_id, c.cmpnt_name, ssd.dwg_id

FROM component c, spec_sheet_data ssd

WHERE c.cmpnt_id = ssd.cmpnt_id and c.cmpnt_id > 0 and ssd.spec_form_id > 0

) ta ON (ta.dwg_id = drawing.dwg_id 
and replace(ta.cmpnt_name, ' ', '') <> drawing.dwg_name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET replace(ta.cmpnt_name, ' ', '') = drawing.dwg_name
```

Merge 2 updating the cs_tag_name = trimmed cmpnt_name ...

```
MERGE INTO control_system_tag
USING 
(
SELECT c.cmpnt_id, c.cmpnt_name

FROM component c

WHERE c.cmpnt_id > 0

) tb ON (tb.cmpnt_id = control_system_tag.cmpnt_id and 
replace(tb.cmpnt_name, ' ', '') <> control_system_tag.cs_tag_name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET replace(tb.cmpnt_name, ' ', '') = control_system_tag.cs_tag_name
```

Answer (score 0):

MERGE is for (INSERT and UPDATE) and sometimes DELETE.
You have only UPDATE. Why do you need MERGE? Use UPDATE!

next:

```
SET replace(tb.cmpnt_name, ' ', '') = control_system_tag.cs_tag_name
```

will not work, column name should be on the left side:

```
SET control_system_tag.cs_tag_name = replace(tb.cmpnt_name, ' ', '')
```

Here is update statement:

```
UPDATE drw set
    dwg_name = lace(c.cmpnt_name, ' ', '')
FROM drawing drw, component c, spec_sheet_data ssd
WHERE  c.cmpnt_id = ssd.cmpnt_id 
and c.cmpnt_id > 0 
and ssd.spec_form_id > 0
and ta.dwg_id = drw.dwg_id 
and drw.dwg_name = lace(c.cmpnt_name, ' ', '')
```

Comment: OK, so more like this ....UPDATE drawing
USING 
(
SELECT c.cmpnt_id, c.cmpnt_name, ssd.dwg_id

FROM component c, spec_sheet_data ssd

WHERE c.cmpnt_id = ssd.cmpnt_id and c.cmpnt_id > 0 and ssd.spec_form_id > 0

) ta ON (ta.dwg_id = drawing.dwg_id 
and replace(ta.cmpnt_name, ' ', '') <> drawing.dwg_name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET drawing.dwg_name = replace(ta.cmpnt_name, ' ', '')

Comment: oops sorry, not sure how to format in the comments ... :$